# Exclude specific packages from bundle in Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to find a way to exclude specific package of a subdepedency from my Webpack bundle. I tried many ways, my recent attempt is to (ab)use the externals options like:

```
externals: [
    function externals(context, request, callback) {
        if (
        context.includes('ui-lib/node_modules/react-dom/') ||
        context.includes('ui-lib/node_modules/d3/') ||
        context.includes('ui-lib/node_modules/lodash/')
        ) {
        return false;
        }
        callback();
    },
],
```

Without success, is any other way to achieve that?

I have a vendors bundle that looks like:

[image]

I want to exclude the duplicate packages under the node-modules, e.g. react-dom.

Entry

```
entry: {
  app: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, './../index.dev.js')],
  vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'd3'],
},
```

CommonChunk

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'vendor',
  filename: 'vendorbundle.js',
  chunks: ['app'],
  minChunks(module) {
    return module.context && module.context.includes('node_modules');
  },
}),
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to exclude a specific package in the loader config:

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules\/SUBDEPENDENCY_PATH/]
  },
```

**Updated:**

Ah okay makes sense, in that case, I would make a separate chunk for just that package. Then using HTMLWebpackPlugin, you can tell it to ignore that chunk and not pull it into the app:

```
entry: {
  sub: ["subdependency"],
  app: "./entry"
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: "sub",
    filename: "sub.js"
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    excludeChunks: ['sub']
  })
]
```

**Update 2:**

Sounds like what you want is to [dedupe dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe). You can't do this using Webpack, you'll need to use npm or yarn:

For example, consider this dependency graph:

```
a
+-- b <-- depends on c@1.0.x
|   `-- c@1.0.3
`-- d <-- depends on c@~1.0.9
    `-- c@1.0.10
```

In this case, npm-dedupe will transform the tree to:

```
a
+-- b
+-- d
`-- c@1.0.10
```

Comment: That will exclude it from being parsed by the loader, not to not being included in the bundle.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis Updated answer. Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: Its depedency of a depedency, entry is not able to find that.

Comment: How do you expect that dependency to work if you don't include it's subdependencies? I don't think that could ever work. They will have to be packaged together somewhere.

Comment: I would suggest chunking off the main dependency then and you can conditionally load it if needed.

Comment: Update with a screenshot.

Comment: Well, it should be out of the box.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis Updated answer with instructions for deduping dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, external libraries that use React need to declare it as `peerDepedency`. Doing that removed one of the `react-dom` instances:

[image]