# Is there a way to load JS file without require?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to load a javascript file without require, but with fs for example?
I know that for json files I can do:

```
const jsonFile = JSON.Parse(fs.readFileSync("./jsonfile.json")
```

Is there a way to do the same for a javascript file?

The reason I am asking is because, i have a configuration file that I kinda want to detach from my app, because when I bundle it with webpack, I cant exclude the config file.

I have tries to directly read it, but I just got some raw format in a buffer:

```
const jsFile = fs.readFileSync("./jsFile.js")
```

**EDIT ANSWER:** I was able to do it by utilizing readFileSync and eval:

```
const jsFile = eval(fs.readFileSync("./jsFile.js", "utf-8"));
```

Keep in mind that if you are requiring other files within that file, the paths change! They will **NOT** be relative to `jsFile.js`, but relative to the **file which reads the `jsFile.js`**

Comment: It'd be theoretically possible, like with `eval`, just strange. Better to find another method, probably by working with webpack

Comment: Yeah it is strange, I just cant find another way to exclude the file from the webpack bundling.

Comment: See the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586605/exclude-specific-packages-from-bundle-in-webpack does that solve the problem?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have tried it, but it seems that this approach has been deprecated. However, I have managed to do it with eval(fs.readFileSync("jsfile.js", "utf-8"))

Comment: *"The reason I am asking is because, i have a configuration file that I kinda want to detach from my app, because when I bundle it with webpack, I cant exclude the config file."* Can you elaborate?

Comment: @FelixKling The file is large and it contains a complex configuration object for my app, I don't want that file to be bundled with the rest of the app (I can't do it with json), I want to still be able to edit it after the app has been bundled. So essentially I want to end up with two files bundle.js and config.js, bundle is the whole app bundled excluding the code in config.js, and config.js is the same config.js as it was before bundling, so that I can still modify it.

Comment: I just saw your other question... :)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do it by utilizing readFileSync and eval:

```
const jsFile = eval(fs.readFileSync("./jsFile.js", "utf-8"));
```

Keep in mind that if you are requiring other files within that file, the paths change! They will **NOT** be relative to `jsFile.js`, but relative to the **file which reads the `jsFile.js`**